# Перенос chart-a на новую форму

Tags: c#, диаграммы

На первой форме есть Chart.
Во второй форме я в конструкторе принимаю chart с первой формы и присваюю его на место чарта со второй формы.

```
 public Config(Chart chart,Term[] terms)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //это не работает
        this.chart1 = chart;

        this.TermNameComboBox.Items.AddRange(terms.Select(t => t.LinguisticVariableName).ToArray());

    }
```

Хочу поработать с сериями и внешним видом (настройка макс, мин по иксу) и вернуться к первой форме. Копироваяние не происходит. Почему и как исправить?

Ссылка присваевается. Скажем, если сделать

```
chart1.Series.Add(new Series("add"));
```

То серия на первом чарте появиться. А мне нужен именно увидеть вид первого чарта на второй форме.

Comment: `chart.Parent = this;`

Comment: @Igor, Можно подробнее? Пока что не получилось